# Write to Native folder on SD card?

Tags: android, permissions, sd-card

Kitkat disallowed apps to write to any folder in SD card.
Apps can only write to native folders residing in storage/external_SD/Android/data/com.example.myapp/

My question is how to allow the app to write to its native folder?

Currently it generates an EACCESS exception.

(PS, AVD app implements this, but how?)

Comment: "Apps can only write to native folders residing in storage/external_SD/Android/data/com.example.myapp/" -- no, they can write to locations returned by the `getExternalFilesDirs()` method on `Context`. There is no requirement that they have the path that you listed.

Comment: `Kitkat disallowed apps to write to any folder in SD card.` **NOT TRUE**.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein How is it not true? I searched a million ways to get my app to write and modify my files in "External SDcard" (not the emulated one) with no luck :(

Comment: @CommonsWare I used the method and it returns the "/storage/elumated/0" path, i.e the internal memory and not the external SD. I was wondering how some firms got their apps to write to the external SD card..

Comment: `getExternalFilesDirs()` -- note the plural -- may return locations on removable media that your app can write to. I wrote [this blog post](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) that describes the situation with removable media, which may help clear things up for you.

Comment: In your system settings, choose the external sdcard as your primary storage... done!